# add inputt textfield when selected item dropdown in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, dropdown

is it possible to add widget input text field  when I selected item 'other' dropdown in flutter?
this is for flutter mobile android

[image]

my code

```
List <String> klasifikasi = [
'Fatality',
'Lainnya'];

DropdownButton<String>(
                  focusColor:Colors.white,
                  value: _chosenValue,
                  //elevation: 5,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  iconEnabledColor:Colors.blue,
                  items: klasifikasi.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value,style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black),),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  hint:Text(
                    "Klasifikasi Insiden",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                  ),

                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    setState(() {

                      _chosenValue = value;
                      if (_chosenValue == klasifikasi){
                        return Scaffold(
                          appBar: AppBar(),
                          body: Center(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                               child: _buildTextField(
                                  labelText: 'Lainnya',
                                  controller: _lainCtrl,
                                ),
                            ),
                          ),

                        );

                      }
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

when I selected 'lainnya' showing textfield to input value

Comment: I am confused why you are returning a scaffold inside a set state method. Where is that even being returned to? This is very strange way of coding it. It would be much easier if you Just layout the whole screen the use an inline if statement to hide /show the text input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this,

```
bool _showTextField = false;
    Column(
      children: [
        DropdownButton<String>(
            focusColor: Colors.white,
            value: _chosenValue,
            //elevation: 5,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            iconEnabledColor: Colors.blue,
            items: klasifikasi.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(
                  value,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
            hint: Text(
              "Klasifikasi Insiden",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            ),
            onChanged: (String value) {
              setState(() {
                _chosenValue = value;
                if (_chosenValue == klasifikasi.last) {
                  _showTextField = true;
                } else {
                  _showTextField = false;
                }
              });
            }),
        Visibility(
          visible: _showTextField,
          child: //Your textfield here,
        ),
      ],
    );
```

i hope that will be help you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Put you dropdown button in a column,

```
bool addtextfield = false;
if (_chosenValue == klasifikasi){
    
    setState((){

      addtextfield = true;
    });
}
addtextfield == true?
//Show ur input field
:Container(),
```

Comment: is this can use for i selected string 'Lainnya" ? or this method for all string in dropdown items?

Comment: i try if (_chosenValue == klasifikasi[9]){
    
    setState((){

      addtextfield = true;
    });
}

 addtextfield == true ? _buildTextField(

                                  labelText: 'Lainnya',
                                  controller: _lainCtrl,)
                                    : Container();

its not showing